# How to use IPython module in web IDEs

Tags: python, html, web, ipython, replit

Hello I'm working on a resume website and wanted to embed an IDE that would run my python code in the site. The problem is it won't run in the IDEs because one of the modules isn't there. I'm really new with this stuff so I would love some help.

I get the following: ImportError: No module named IPython on line 6

Is there way to get it to work so I can embed it to my website? If it is not possible I'll just include the code itself. If there is a way to embed my program without using a web IDE I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can install easily IPython to your web server.

Documentation: https://ipython.org/install.html

---

Alternative solution is you can embed other site python interpreter with your code.

Example: https://trinket.io/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Actually I was not clear enough asking the question. I meant when using interpreters like trinket or repl, my code does not work or that is what I would embed into my site. I found the reason is because these sites use old versions of python when my script is in the newer ones. I'm thinking of using Jovian.ml, apparently that will work. If you have other suggestions I would love to know. Thanks again!